# Show AreaTitle when hovered over on circle svg object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm working on a school project showing a world map made from dots. In this world map I want to give people the idea on how much terrorism there is in the world and which locations has been hit in the past year(s).

I'm currently struggling with a text hover on one of these 'circles'. I want to make text appear when hovered over a certain 'circle object' or dot. I've given these specific circles an `AreaTitle`, but I can't seem to find out how to show this `AreaTitle` in like a hover textbox.

```js
var xCords = [
        '171.8'
    ];
    var yCords = [
        '23.6'
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < xCords.length; i++) {
      var newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
      newCircle.setAttribute('cx', xCords[i]);
      newCircle.setAttribute('cy', yCords[i]);
      newCircle.setAttribute('r', '1');
      newCircle.setAttribute('class', i);
      if(i === 1) {
        var areaTitle;
       newCircle.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                areaTitle = 'Istanbul';
                newCircle.setAttribute('class', 'istanbul');
                break;
        }
        newCircle.setAttribute('title', ''+areaTitle+'');
        $('#worldmap').append(newCircle);
      } else {
       newCircle.setAttribute('fill', '#5c5c5c');
        $('#worldmap').prepend(newCircle);
      }

    }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}


@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
    stroke-width: 1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: rgba(215, 18, 0, 0.1);
    /*stroke-width: 40;*/
  }
}

circle[fill="#ff0000"] {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /*stroke-width: 30;*/
  animation: blink 1.5s infinite ease-out;
}

.istanbul {
  stroke-width: 30;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Terrorism</title>


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 900 720" enable-background="new 0 0 900 720" xml:space="preserve" id="worldmap">
</svg>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
</div>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13jMQ.png)

Comment: please, create a jsfiddle so we can edit

Comment: I've created a JsFiddle but i have shorten the xy Cords because the text limit was reached.

Comment: this is full of errors: referenced files that don't exist, unsecure js libraries... please create a https://jsfiddle.net and be more specific if you want some help

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements don't use `title` attributes. You need to use a `<title>` element instead.

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="70" fill="red">
    <title>This is a circle</title>
  </circle>
</svg>
```